# Masking &amp; for AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, validation

This is a follow-up to a question I asked a few weeks back.

The following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="start_ajax_request('url.php&key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3')">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

will **not** validate in the W3C validator as HTML 4.01 transitional, wrongly, as far as I can see. It complains about entities and wants each ampersand converted to `&amp;`. `&amp;` in the given context however, would be wrong, because my Ajax request needs plain ampersands and will break when fed `&amp;`.

Is there a way to mask/escape the ampersands in this example so that it's still a valid URL that will pass through the Ajax request, and shuts up the validator?

Comment: I don't even see why the validator would complain about *that* - this is simply a string inside a function. Therefore there is no way for the validator to know what that string means semantically - that it is supposed to be an URL. Did you test this very example in the validator?

Comment: you may need to add the click event from within a script file or script block to prevent this.

Comment: @Franz: I updated the example, try it for yourself. I can't see anything wrong with it.
@Josh: Yes, but I really want to avoid that right now :)

Comment: Oh, ok. Then the validator is more intelligent than I thought ;)

Comment: I would say, it is more intrusive than it should be. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing with the JS escape() function and by passing the ampersand as %26  The same way I am sure you see spaces passed as %20

Hope it works

Comment: This did it for me: urlencode()ing the URL in PHP, and adding unescape() to the JS. Not perfect but works for me, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could assign the onclick in your JavaScript. This is better because it keeps your markup cleaner. Here's a jquery solution.

```
$('a').bind('click', function() {
  start_ajax_request('url.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3');
});
```

Comment: Try adding the cdata block. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355043/how-do-i-escape-an-ampersand-in-a-javascript-string-so-that-the-page-will-validat

Comment: It looks like you have a solution, but I was able to get a CDATA block to work in an inline onclick.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [encodeURIComponent() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) to send the URL string and then decode it in the reciever. If you're using PHP, you need to do something like this:

```
utf8_decode(rawurldecode(str));
```

Comment: I don't think this is the point, as the problem is not that URI components are wrognly recognized as a URI, but that the URI is being rejected by the validator. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert and i don't know if my answer is exactly related to your question.

I was having a similar problem, but in the oposite direction, i noticed that when i created an onclick event with parameters received via ajax in json format, parsed and placed in the document, when i viewed the source code i got something like

```
<a href="#" onclick="qString('blah.php', 'ipp=2&amp;ord=0');">blah</a>
```

but that didn't stop the app from working, and i never had a problem before because i dont use & as part of a parameter value, and if the value is user input i use encodeURIComponent to encode the value.

So i went on and discarted any json parse issues or ut8 related issues, thats when i realized that when using javascript inside html having & amp; instead of & is actually correct.

So in my case what i thought for a moment was not ok, is ok for the W3C valitador.

Try:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function foo(url) {
        alert(url.indexOf('&'));
        alert(url.indexOf('&amp;'));
        return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="foo('url.php?key1=val1&amp;key2=val2&amp;key3=val3');">Test</a>
</body>
</html>
```