# How to escape & in a POST request in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, escaping

i have an input element with & in value:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Biografie, životopisy, osudy, Domácí rock&amp;pop" />
```

When i try sending it through an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin/kategorie/add/link.json",
    data: "id="+id+"&value="+value+"&type="+type,
    error: function(){alert('Chyba! Reloadněte prosím stránku.');}
});
```

the post data that actually gets sent is:

```
id: 1
pop:
type: e
value: Biografie, životopisy, osudy, Domácí rock
```

*Note that all the variables in data are defined and value contains $(thatInputElement).attr('value').

How can I escape the `&amp;` properly so that post field `value` would contain `Biografie, životopisy, osudy, Domácí rock&amp;pop`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can set your `data` option as an object and let jQuery do the encoding, like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/admin/kategorie/add/link.json",
  data: { id: id, value: value, type: type },
  error: function(){ alert('Chyba! Reloadněte prosím stránku.'); }
});
```

You *can* encode each value using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_javascript_1.5_reference:global_functions:encodeuricomponent), like this:

```
encodeURIComponent(value)
```

But the first option much simpler/shorter in most cases :)

Comment: Thank you, this with encodeURIComponent did the trick, I assume i can decode it on the server-side (PHP) using urldecode($var)?

Comment: @cypher - It should be automatically decoded, but it's been forever since a PHP application so double check me on that.

Comment: Wow, I've been doing this wrong for 2 years! This made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this syntax?

```
 data: {"id":id, "value": value, "type": type }
```

Comment: This syntax works, and is the better option as mentioned in Nick's answer, because jQuery will encode the object behind the scenes for you.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript function "escape()" should work and on the server the method HttpUtility.UrlDecode should unescape. There may be some exceptions. Additionally if you need to decode on the client, there is an equivalent "unescape()" on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML character code for & instead: \u0026

Comment: See this related post for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355043/how-do-i-escape-an-ampersand-in-a-javascript-string-so-that-the-page-will-validat

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object and pass that along instead:

```
vars = new Object();
vars.id = id;
vars.value = value;
vars.type = type;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/admin/kategorie/add/link.json",
  data: vars,
  error: function(){ alert('Chyba! Reloadněte prosím stránku.'); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace & with {and} at client side, then replace {and} to & at server side