# Javascript ajax post

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape & in a POST request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319123/how-to-escape-in-a-post-request-in-jquery)

I am using the jQuery ajax to do auto complete on my website. I am running into a problem though, an & can be stored in the database and that just wreaks havoc with my posted variables.
What it needs to do: `ajax=true&search=t&w` (With the ampersand and w part of the search variable)

What it does though is it creates a new post variable of `w`.

Is there a way to block the ampersand from creating a new post variable, or do I just need to change the `&'s` to and/And

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: page_url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'ajax=true&search='+$('#search_string').val(),
    success: function(data){

    }
});
```

If the values are encoded, how will the database handle the encoded &?

Comment: You need to properly encode your parameters.  Please show us your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the value passed to data as an object it will painlessly encode:

```
data: {ajax:isAjaxTrue, search: searchValue}
```

see: [How to escape & in a POST request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319123/how-to-escape-in-a-post-request-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use url encoder to avoid special characters in a parameter value .

```
encodeURIComponent(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `encodeURIComponent()`.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: encodeURIComponent('ajax=true&search='+$('#search_string').val()),
    ...
});
```