# Ajax request with using rxjs problems with ampersand

Tags: javascript, ajax, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm using rxjs in my application.

In **package.json** my rxjs dependency is `"rxjs": "^5.2.0"`

From that I'm using the ajax module:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'
```

I can't find the documentation for the ajax function.

My code:

```
let categories = action.payload.subcategories.map(cat => cat.id)
let shop = JSON.stringify(action.payload.shop)
action.payload.categories = JSON.stringify(categories)
action.payload.shop = shop
return ajax
  .post('http://192.xxx.xxxx:4000/products', action.payload, {
    'Content-': 'application/json'
  })
```

I'm getting an issue where if the `shop` object has an ampersand in one of its fields, that breaks the json.stringified object being sent.

How do I allow ampersands in the text fields of the objects being json.stringified without breaking the field?

Do I have to url encode it? It will just mean a bit more work on the back end to decode so I'm looking at my options.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3319145/3935156) seems like an easy way to do it although I'm not using jquery and I don't know how to set request type to data object in the `ajax.post` function being used.

action.payload:

[image]

The actual form data being sent (network tab in developer console)

[image]

I noticed when I used `encodeURIComponent()` in javascript it did change the payload massively. I have the backend decoding json currently so would like to avoid changing the payload that much if possible. The back end is in Elixir.

Comment: Can you please post an example of action.payload (just before running the ajax) and the error you get?

Comment: @dzejdzej I've just posted them now in the images. The error is in the Elixir programming language. I just posted the image which shows the ampersand breaking the string in the shop name.