# jQuery $().html escapes &-sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var alt = json_data['alt']; // some text
var url = json_data['url']; // some url

var img_url = '<img src=\'/' + url + '?h=100&w=100\' alt=\'' + alt + '\'>';
$('#imagepreview').html(img_url); // translates to <img src="/some_url?h=100&amp;w=100" alt="some_text">
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Actually this is good as it produces valid HTML. ampersands must be escaped like this in urls for the HTML code to be valid. So I see no problem here, it should be working.

Comment: Ok, but in this example I want the & not the &amp;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355043/how-do-i-escape-an-ampersand-in-a-javascript-string-so-that-the-page-will-valida

Answer (score 4):

`&amp;` is actually the valid URL, not &

Comment: Ok, but in this example I want the & not the &amp;

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't see that happen, but nevertheless you should do it this way:

```
var img = $('<img />', {
    src: '/' + url + '?h=100&w=100',
    alt: alt
}).appendTo('#imagepreview');
```

That makes sure any escaping is done properly, such as the `alt` attribute!

Comment: This translates to <img alt="some_alt" src="/some_url?h=100&amp;w=100">

Comment: @CasvanNoort I think the way you have determined that is not the same for every browser; why should the url not have `&amp;`?

Comment: @CasvanNoort have you tried this: `console.log($('#imagepreview img').attr('src'));`

Answer (score 0):

You must use \u0026 instead of &