# Using ampersand sign within client-side template and render it with thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf, jsrender, jsviews

I use [jsrender](http://www.jsviews.com/) lib for client-side template generation but the whole website's output is processed by thymeleaf (spring mvc). The problem is that js template contains condtiion i.e.

```
<script id="main-menu-form-tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
        {{if (index && (index == 0 || ...
```

but thymeleaf requires all the ampersands be escaped as `&amp;`, but this causes jsrender to fail. Another solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/355047/705869), but jsrender fails as well because of unknown syntax.

Is there any way to output script's content without parsing it with thymeleaf engine?

Answer (score 2):

JsRender lets you register templates from strings, as well as from script blocks.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#compiletmpl.

So instead of writing:

```
var mainTemplate = $.templates("#main-menu-form-tmpl");
```

and then calling `mainTemplate.render(...)` or `mainTemplate.link(...)` etc. you can instead remove your template script block and instead pass your template markup as a string to `$.templates()` as in:

```
var mainTemplate = $.templates("... {{if (index && (index == 0 || ...");
...
```

Or if you want you can keep the script block declaration, but with escaped ampersands and then get the contents of the script block as a string, unescape the ampersands, and pass that string to your template definition:

```
var mainTemplateString = $("#main-menu-form-tmpl").text().replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
var mainTemplate = $.templates(mainTemplateString);
...
```

Alternatively you can wrap your template block in `<![CDATA` and again, strip the wrapper to get the real template markup string you want to pass to the template definition:

```
var mainTemplateString = $("#main-menu-form-tmpl").text().slice(16, -10);
var mainTemplate = $.templates(mainTemplateString);
...
```